# Django - Hide labels in inline

Tags: django, django-admin, django-inline-models

How to hide labels in Django inlines?

[image]

Comment: I'm also currently looking for a solution for this that does not involve modifying the model as referenced by @grisuu. I attempted to look through the django docs for Tabular inline but came up short. 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline

Answer (score -1):

When I got you right, you can set the verbose_name to empty string in your model by adding the Attribute

```
verbose_name=''
```

to your field like

```
street = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name='')
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to change a semantical metadata of a model field just to hack the admin into hiding something.